# have an HTML document with a linked Javascript I am trying to add an alert message when a submit button is clicked. How do I do this?

Tags: javascript, html, alerts

I have a form and within the form on my HTML i have a submit button. I want an alert to pop up when clicked that says Thank you for contacting us we will respond shortly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and What topics can I ask about here?

Comment: You can listen to 'click' or 'submit' event of your button.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Ele said.. this can be found in a ton of places.. but its very simple..
Just do the following:

This is in the html:

```
<button onClick="MyFunction()">Submit</button>
```

This is the JavaScript:

```
<script>
function MyFunction() {
    alert("Thank you for contacting us, we will respond shortly.");
}
</script>
```

Comment: you have a typo in `myFunction`